# handle C++ caused crashes in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, crash

When I write behind code in iOS application:

```
string s; s.resize(-1);
```

it will lead the application crash.

Are there any way to handle this crash? I try to use KSCrash but no effect.

Comment: You can use exception handling to handle this crash. It should throw an exception of type std::length_error

Comment: Might be worth writing that up as a formal answer, @Asesh , but first, user8751745 are you deliberately trying to throw an exception? You can't `resize` a negative number, the parameter is unsigned.

Comment: @user4581301 After Googling KSCrash, looks like he is trying to use crash reporter. He should have stated that as his query is not clear enough

Comment: I dont know how to handle this crash, NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler not work for C++ and SetUnhandledExceptionFilter not work in iOS.

Comment: @user8751745 Do you want to handle this internally in your code or do  you plan to use crash reporting service?

Comment: I just want to know how to handle it when the crash happen.

Comment: @user8751745 Google "Google crashpad", it' used by Chrome too

Comment: Crash pad might not work for iOS so you better look for tutorials of KSCrash

Comment: I use KSCrash now, but the problem is that it cant get the crash call stack when I write "string s; s.resize(-1);"in demo.So I need a function that when the crash happen it can be called.

Comment: Can't you just enable sufficient warnings to prevent implicit `signed` → `unsigned` conversions from compiling?

Answer (score 1):

`string.resize()` accepts an *unsigned* integer value. Compilers will often convert -1 you have supplied (which is a signed integer value) to an unsigned integer that has the same bit pattern (usually the largest possible unsigned integer).

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/), resize throws `length_error` when the supplied length is greater than [`max_size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/max_size/). However, since `max_size` has nothing to do with how much memory is *actually* available for use by your program, catching it doesn't preclude the possibility that the application is crashing because the system doesn't have enough memory to satisfy this request, which very likely is what happened here.

---

With that out of the way...
What are you trying to accomplish here? It would have been way easier to add an `if` check instead.

Comment: If I not use try&catch, are there any way to catch this exception?

Comment: Actually I just want to handle the crash when it happen that I can save the call stack. The problem is that some crash like above I cant handle it.

Comment: You're at least as likely to get `std::bad_alloc` as `std::length_error`, I think.

Comment: You need to prevent this exception before it happens. Memory exceptions can't be reliably caught without hacking into the CRT.